# VSTS Pending changes files are not checked out

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I am facing some strange with VSTS and visual studio 2017. I was working on some changes since last 2 weeks and since last Friday I could see all my pending changes.

However On Monday when I tried same to check my pending changes I am not able to see any file checked out and it says no pending changes. I checked my changes in one of the file and I found those changes but then in this case my file must have been checked out as per my knowledge.

Now I am not able to see any checked out file and my pending changes list is empty. Pleas help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons for this. Below are some of the common reasons I could think of:

Go to File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control and make sure that you have Project binding ON. If not click on 'Bind' button. Now if you edit any file it will be get automatically checked-out and will be available in 'Pending Changes' list.

For now, go to 'View -> Other Windows -> Source Control Explorer', right click on project folder and select 'Compare'. It will show the list of files that differ from TFS. Check out the files to make those available for 'check-in'

Also make sure that in 'Compare' list 'Latest' column shows 'Yes'